# Table view not display Data from Facebook Login

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uitableview

I am newbie in `Facebook Log in` and i know this question asked many times but i not get solution at Please help me For this.

I create an app that contain Login With Facebook and it is Working As i want but when Application was Launch Then in my `viewDidLoad` method i Write a Code like as

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.qpinname=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
self.address=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
self.qpinType=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[super viewDidLoad];
self.fbLogin.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
self.fbLogin.delegate=self;
[self.view addSubview:self.fbLogin];
[self.view addSubview:self.personalTable];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appDidBecomeActive:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
{
    [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
        if (!error)
        {
            self.username=user.name;
        }
    }];
    NSLog(@"Session Is Open");
    self.personalTable.hidden=FALSE;
    [self connectWithFacebook];
}
else
{
     NSLog(@"Session Is not open");
}
}
- (void)connectWithFacebook
{
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
}
```

And My App Delegate Method I write a Method `openSessionWithAllowLoginUI` like as

```
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
{
    NSArray *permissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];

return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                          allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                         if (error)
                                         {
                                             NSLog (@"Handle error %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                         }
                                         else
                                         {
                                             [self checkSessionState:state];
                                         }
                                     }];
 }

- (void) checkSessionState:(FBSessionState)state {
switch (state)
{
    case FBSessionStateOpen:
    {
        RequestViewController *request=[[RequestViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"RequestViewController"bundle:nil];
        [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
            if (!error)
            {
                request.username=user.name;
                NSLog(@"User Name %@",request.username);
                PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MapInfo"];
                if (request.username.length !=0)
                {
                    [query whereKey:@"Admin" equalTo:request.username];
                    [query whereKey:@"Type" equalTo:@"Personal"];
                    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
                     {
                         if (!error)
                         {
                             request.address=[objects valueForKey:@"Address"];
                             request.qpinType=[objects valueForKey:@"Name"];
                             request.qpinname=[objects valueForKey:@"Type"];
                             request.locationDictionary=[objects valueForKey:@"Location"];
                             request.latitude=[request.locationDictionary valueForKey:@"lat"];
                             request.longitude=[request.locationDictionary valueForKey:@"lng"];
                             NSLog(@"Self.Qpin Name %@ %@",request.latitude,request.longitude);
                             request.personalTable.hidden=FALSE;
                             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                 [request.personalTable reloadData];
                             });
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
                             NSLog(@"Error: %@", errorString);
                             [request.personalTable reloadData];
                         }
                     }];
                }
            }
        }];

    }
        break;
    case FBSessionStateCreated:
        break;
    case FBSessionStateCreatedOpening:
        break;
    case FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded:
        break;
    case FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended:
        break;
    case FBSessionStateClosed:
        break;
    case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

Then I get array Data at login as i want but it is Not Display in my `TableView` and in my `Tableview View Controller` I write a Code for `viewWillAppear` method like as

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
    || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended)
{
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MapInfo"];
if (self.username.length !=0)
{
    [query whereKey:@"Admin" equalTo:self.username];
    [query whereKey:@"Type" equalTo:@"Personal"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error)
         {
             self.address=[objects valueForKey:@"Address"];
             self.qpinType=[objects valueForKey:@"Name"];
             self.qpinname=[objects valueForKey:@"Type"];
             self.locationDictionary=[objects valueForKey:@"Location"];
             self.latitude=[self.locationDictionary valueForKey:@"lat"];
             self.longitude=[self.locationDictionary valueForKey:@"lng"];
             NSLog(@"Self.Qpin Name %@ %@",self.latitude,self.longitude);
             [self.personalTable reloadData];
         }
         else
         {
             NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", errorString);
         }
        }];
}
}
else
{
    self.username=@"";
}
}
```

Then it Display Data at when my `ViewWillAppear` but i want data at my Application launch Please Give me Solution For this.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Parse.com apis ?

Comment: @Joge yes. but i get Data Value in app delegate but not update it to my viewController please give me solution for it. how it update from app delegate to view controller.

Comment: Are you getting data in your ViewWillAppear after login ?

Comment: Yes but i want to Data at viewdidload.

Comment: your viewdidload in not calling at that time ... so you need to that in ViewWillAppear...

Comment: @Joge yes but i want it when app was launch it was possible? here i got data on my app delegate but i want to update it in my viewController if it is possible or not? on  viewdidload?

Comment: Just add FBLoginDelegate and override its login method.
It will execute after user login and at that method you should reload tableView 
It will solve your problem cent percent...